# Editing buddypress css not working correctly

Tags: css, wordpress, buddypress

so basically i made a child theme of color mag and copied the buddy press css into my child theme like this /buddypress/css/buddypress.css (this is what they told in the forums)

so from this

```
#buddypress #header-cover-image {
    background-color: #c5c5c5;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

i added this


 #buddypress #header-cover-image {
    background-color: #c5c5c5;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NKHS.jpg)

am i doing something wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ; at end of border-color: black. This could be the problem

Comment: that must be a typo but i tried everything but it doesent seem to work any way i tried changing other thing in the cover section but nothing seems to help

Comment: and check out the image i posted it only adds a dot to it not the whole thing

Comment: I always put buddypress.css in themefolder/css/buddypress.css and I never had any issue. I think you are placing your file in wrong folder.

Comment: i do it like this theme/buddypress/css/buddypress.css

Comment: so i found some thing in color mag it  had something like border: 0; i tried blocking it with firebug and wallah everythings working now thanks for your time though

Comment: yo bro one more thing like how do you make a drop down list 
can you like write some css for  me of 'activity' or 'profile' how you do it i ll figure out others myself.

Comment: Can you accept my answer if that works for you? Can you give me some example about your drop down menu.?

Comment: yeah i will if u help me out :p jk

well nothing to fancy bro just a regular drop down like when i hove mouse over 'profile' it drops down its sub nav like 'change pic' or on 'activity' personal mention drops down and how to stop display entry title on profile page i tried entry-title{display:none;} and it turned it off from the whole website

Comment: i just wana get rid of the ugly design it creates on default template